# UpdateOpensuse 15.0 -> 15.1 => Areca Raid disks not regignized anymore

Tags: raid, opensuse

Hi I updated my openSuse Leap 15.0 to 15.1 and now I cannot Access my Areaca Raid disks anymore:

1. I have the "ARC-1883IX-12" controller and while Booting all Raid Sets get recognized.
2. In Linux they are missing e.g. the command `lsscsi` or `sginfo -l` does not show them.

Everything worked before OS upgrade.

If I try to run the `Areca CLI, Version: 1.15.8` with the command `cli64` then I get the following error:

> Error: Please check the (arcmsr & sg) drivers are installed properly.

Both linux kernel modules  are loaded:

```
suseServer:~ # lsmod | egrep 'arcmsr|sg'
arcmsr                 53248  0
sg                     45056  0
```

The version of the `sg` kernel module did not change with the update.
`SCSI generic (sg) driver  3.5.36 => before and after update`

The version of the Kernel module with the openSuse 15.1 Server is:

```
suseServer15.1:~ # modinfo arcmsr
filename:       /lib/modules/4.12.14-lp151.28.32-default/kernel/drivers/scsi/arcmsr/arcmsr.ko
version:        v1.40.00.05-20180309
```

If I look to the mirrored production server on openSuse 15.0:

```
suseServer15.0:~ # modinfo arcmsr
filename:       /lib/modules/4.12.14-lp150.12.67-default/kernel/drivers/scsi/arcmsr/arcmsr.ko
version:        v1.30.00.22-20151126
```

My simple approach to load the older `v1.30` version of the `arcmsr.ko` file that I copied from the `suseServer15.0` in the target directory `/lib/modules/4.12.14-lp151.28.32-default/kernel/drivers/scsi/arcmsr/arcmsr.ko` resulted in the error:

```
suseServer15.1:~ # /sbin/modprobe arcmsr
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'arcmsr': Exec format error
```

My current Raid Controller Firmware looks like this:
[image]

For me the next step would be updating the Firmware but does anyone else have an idea what I could do ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it:

The solution was to download the newer percompiled kernel module from the website and replace the `/lib/modules/4.12.14-lp151.28.32-default/kernel/drivers/scsi/arcmsr/arcmsr.ko` file.

https://www.areca.com.tw/support/downloads.html

[Here is the WORKING link, the original one from the webpage does not work "." instead of"_" in the URL](http://www.areca.us/support/s_linux/driver/opensuse/15_1.zip)